# How to click on button on Popup Window in Selenium Webdriver by using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please Help me how to click on button on Popup Window in  Selenium Webdriver by using Java, i have apply more and more code but i am not success, please help me . I have also attached Please see a lock  and give me reply my answer please|||||
[image]

Comment: Could you share actual navigation URL to reach that page?

Comment: and steps to navigate to this popup??

Comment: Go To Course Page, click on Cooking Fundamentals I, Click on Mise en Place after that see this popup.

Comment: Why not google for your problem? It would have lead you back to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694507/how-to-handle-popup-window-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403949/how-to-handle-pop-up-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java) answered questions about the same topic.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got it answer

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[15]/div/img")).click();
    Set<String> RecipeHandle = driver.getWindowHandles();
     System.out.println(RecipeHandle);  
     for (String handle1 : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
     {
            System.out.println(handle1);
            driver.switchTo().window(handle1);              
     }
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[4]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/button")).click();
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(3000);**
```

Thanks for erveryone who responding me...