# Selenium upload with sendkeys not working- Since there is a popup before uploading

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I have a scenario where the upload of a file in the webpage which have a browse button and clicking this browse button, the the windows explore window appears. I select the file and click the upload button in the window. Now, there is a overlay popup on the webpage to enter the name of uploading file and click the save button.

This cannot be automated since there is a popup overlay screen before getting uploaded. 
   The below is the code that I have used.

```
WebElement PDFUpload =driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='upload-area'])[2]"));
PDFUpload.sendKeys("C:\\test\\Testuploads\\test.pdf");
```

This working fine when there is no overlay screen after clicking the upload after selecting the file. But when the overlay for naming the uploaded file is implemented in webpage, the test is not running.Tried with robot class as well, its still not working(might be because of the robot class which I put incorrectly). But leave this case because I dont see using robot class is a good practice on this kind of dynamic website which I am working on. Can anyone help?

Comment: check this out: https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle popup window using selenium webdriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694507/how-to-handle-popup-window-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: Its not about handling popup window. Its about uploading a file.
if I use the above mentioned code, the file is not getting uploaded since there is a popup screen  appearing after selecting the file from local machine.

Answer (score 1):

This method is for handling the Windows File Upload dialogue, which cannot be handled using Selenium. Please follow the below steps:

- Click on the File Upload / Choose File button, so that the File
  Upload dialog is displayed.

> ```
> driver.findElement(By.id("uploadbutton")).click;
> ```

- Copy your file's absolute path to the clipboard

> StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("D:/Test/Test1.docx");
>   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss,
>   null);

- Paste the file's absolute path into the File name field of the File
  Upload dialog box

> ```
> //native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys
> Robot robot = new Robot();
>
> robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
> robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
> robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
> robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
> robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
> robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the overlay screen through the automation code itself and then upload file.

Set the css display property to none using Javascript.

Execute javascript through webdriver

```
argument[0].style.display = "none";
```

Where argument[0] is the WebElement referencing to the overlay screen.

I understand this approach is quite debatable as this modifies the original web page, however, if the more important functionality to test is the file upload then it should be okay.